# How to have a page display ".php" extension: linking an external php file in html

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before, but I've been looking around the internet and I can't find an answer that works for me.

I see that some websites display the `.php` extension instead of `.html` or `.htm`. I want to know if there is any way for me to link an external php file in html, similar to the way you link another html page. Ex:

```html
<body>
<a href="example.php">PHP page<a>
</body>
```

Of course, this doesn't actually work, or I wouldn't be asking. When I click the link it brings me to a page with the contents of the php file instead of actually running the script. Is this a problem with the html or the way that I set up the file?

Comment: @LuisE I would prefer just a simple tag or something like that, I'm not a very advanced programmer.

Comment: I think the code I shared is rather simple but ok. The code on your php file "example.php" should indeed be executed when linked this way and the <a> object is clicked. If you have a function declared, you should actually call it in the example.php file. Such as:  //here I call the function -> hello();  //here I declare the function -> function hello(){echo "hello";}

Comment: @LuisE I tested the php link, and the file contained `echo "hi";`, but instead it printed out the actual command. What are you saying I need to do?

Comment: well, the file must contain: <?php echo "hi"; ?>. It should also be running inside some kind of server, but if you have used php already, guess you know that.

Comment: @LuisE That worked, would you mind adding it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636212/283366) in the linked duplicate

Comment: @Phil I would like to do things properly, how can I mark a question as a duplicate? also, if I hadn't asked further questions it would be a little hard to pinpoint what the problem was, should I refrain from making such questions and mark it as a duplicate before asking?

Comment: It's already done, there's nothing more for you to do (other than keep coding of course).

Comment: @Phil I was asking for future answers, and I couldn't stop coding even if I try c:

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking questions (that's how we learn). You didn't do anything wrong. Sometimes when we search for answers, we don't get the exact right keywords and it's hard to find the correct one. That's why StackOverflow has the duplicate system, so others can help you find what you're looking for. Have a great day

Comment: Guys, move this to the chat

Answer (score 1):

You can link the php page with your html page, you have to setup path correctly.
Hope below example will solve your problem,

```
<a href="https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php">Externallink</a>
```

Comment: I don't think OP means it's _that_ kind of _"external php file"_